# Prove vector space is a field...?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the vector space over $\mathbb R$ consisting of all continuous functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$. Equip $V$ with the multiplication $(f \cdot g)(x)=f(x) \cdot g(x)$ for $f,g \in V$ and $\forall x \in \mathbb R$. IF addition is given by the vector space structure, does the multiplication make $V$ into a field? Either prove or disprove which of the field axioms fail.

So basically I need to check and see if $(V$\ ${0_V}$, $\cdot)$ is an abelian group.

First, I checked if $\cdot$ is a binary operation. But, isn't this given? Because for $\cdot: V \times V \to V$ $(f \cdot g)(x) = f(x) \cdot g(x)$ for $f,g \in V$ and $ \forall x \in \mathbb R$. Or would I need to prove that it's bijective?

I showed that associativity holds because $(f \cdot g)(x) \cdot h(x) = f(x) \cdot g(x) \cdot h(x)= f(x) \cdot (g \cdot h) (x)$.

But now I need to show that a multiplicative identity exists (if it does). I'm not sure where exactly to go from here.

Any feedback/advice is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the multiplicative inverse of $f(x)=x$?

Comment: The existence of a multiplicative identity is not what is going to fail. Hint: if $f$ is $0$ at some point, can $f$ have a multiplicative inverse?

Comment: @JpMcCarthy IT would be $\frac{1}{x}$, right?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft No, because you can't divide by zero. But I figured that wasn't a case because I'm considering $(V$\ $0_V$, $\cdot)$? (Although my map didn't reflect that).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Okay, now I understand! Thanks!

Comment: But for example the map $f(x) = x$ (as suggested by others) is not the $0$-map, and yet it is $0$ at a certain point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiplicative identity is actually simple. We are looking for a function $f$ such that for every $h$ and $x$, $f(x)\cdot h(x)=h(x)$. Consider $h(x)=2$ for all $x$, then the only $f$ that would satisfy this equation is $f(x)=1$ for all $x$.

It isn't very hard to show now that this is indeed the multiplicative identity.

However, it is not true, as the comments said, that every function has a multiplicative inverse, what happens with the function $f(x)=x-1$?